# Selenium Grid error no main manifest attribute, in selenium-server-4.0.0-alpha-2.jar

Tags: java, selenium, maven, manifest

I am trying to set up Selenium hub and I am getting this error.

```
no main manifest attribute, in selenium-server-4.0.0-alpha-2.jar

java -jar selenium-server-4.0.0-alpha-2.jar -role hub
```

In Maven I have the correct plugin in POM already. What else could be the issue?

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
   <configuration>
      <archive>
         <manifest>
            <mainClass>com.abc.qr.xyz.MainClass</mainClass>
         </manifest>
      </archive>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Have you built selenium grid jar on your own from sources?

Comment: I downloaded this from Maven repository using Maven POM

mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/… 


<dependency> 
     <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
     <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId> 
    <version>4.0.0-alpha-2</version> 
</dependency>